# Is unrefrigerated kimchi safe?

Tags: food-safety, kimchi

As the question states, is kimchi still safe to eat after spending a few hours unrefrigerated, the time it takes me to get home ?

I'm mostly concerned because my commute home involves time in a heated bus

Comment: shouldn't you be asking if the other bus passengers are safe from the kimchi? I see the headlines now: explosive event rocks commuters...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I make kimchi regularly. It sits on a shelf at room temperature for a week or more, and slowly ferments. Some people ferment it for months. Sure, it likes a [low oxygen partial pressure](http://www.bottlebiology.org/investigations/kimchee_bkgreading.html), but a few hours on a bus isn't going to hurt it.

Answer (score 6):

Kimchi existed long before refrigeration. Infact the sole principle of kimchi is preservation through fermentation. So yes, you can leave it at room temperature for a few hours.

Comment: primary principle perhaps. umami heaven should also get a salute.